# Magento 2: Set default select drop down option

Tags: magento2, forms, input

Is there a way to set the default option for a select drop down on the frontend product page?

At the moment 'Please select...' is the default option.

```
<select name="options[22]" id="select_22" class="required product-custom-option admin__control-select" title="" >
    <option value="" >-- Please Select --</option>
    <option value="22"  price="0" >United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="30"  price="0" >USA</option>
    <option value="40"  price="0" >Europe</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Admin? Frontend? What kind of drop down? Please be more specific and explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Sorry, the frontend, product page. So the user can choose a country from a drop down. At the moment 'Please select...' is the default option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no possibility to set a default product custom option value out of the box. This feature needs to be implemented programmatically. Also, you can try some existing solutions for this purpose. For example the following extension:

https://github.com/magebuzz/Magebuzz_Customoption

I'm not sure how it works on the latest Magento versions but you can check it. The installation should not take much time.